# List view inside Fragment is not getting populated

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I am trying to populate a `ListView` and display it under Fragment. I see that the count is returning correctly (greater than 0) after calling the adapter. Initially I had an issue with `getView` not being called but it was in a way resolved by changing layout_height to wrap_content as suggested by one of the article. I see that `getView` is now called while swiping for one Fragment to another. But `getView` doesn't get called when the Fragment is initially loaded. and also I don't `ListView` is displayed on screen regardless of any action.

First Fragment:

```
public class OneFragment extends Fragment {

public OneFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

//private ListView mListView;
GridView grid;
String[] web = {
        "Doctors","Movies","Dentists"} ;

int[] imageId = {
        R.mipmap.doctors,
        R.mipmap.dentists,
        R.mipmap.restaurants
            };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    int iconSize=getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(android.R.dimen.app_icon_size);

    CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(view.getContext(), iconSize);
    GridView gridview = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid);
    gridview.setAdapter(adapter);

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "You Clicked at " +web[+ position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            ListItemMainFragment nextFrag = new ListItemMainFragment();

            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            ft.replace(((ViewGroup) getView().getParent()).getId(), nextFrag);
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_NONE);// it will anim while calling fragment.
            ft.addToBackStack(null); // it will manage back stack of fragments.
            ft.commit();


        }
    });

    return view;
 }
}
```

Next Fragment:

```
    public class ListItemMainFragment extends Fragment implements Item.DataListener {

    private ListView mListView;
    private ItemAdapter adapter;

    public ListItemMainFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_main, container, false);
        mListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_list_view);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        //final String DBReference = "all/" + position + "/" + web[+position];
        final String DBReference = "all/0/Doctors";
        Item.getRecipesFromDB(ListItemMainFragment.this, DBReference);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void newDataReceived(ArrayList<Item> itemList) {

        adapter = new ItemAdapter(getActivity(), itemList);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        Log.d("records ", String.valueOf((adapter.getCount())));

     }
   }
```

Adapter:

```
  public class ItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ArrayList<Item> mDataSource;

    public ItemAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> items) {
        Log.d("MyApp", "I am here1000A");
        mContext = context;
        mDataSource = items;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    //1
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mDataSource.size();
    }

    //2
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mDataSource.get(position);
    }

    //3
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    //4
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get view for row item
        View rowView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_detail, parent, false);
        Log.d("MyApp", "I am here1000");

        TextView titlePrefixTextView =
                (TextView) rowView.findViewById(com.ferainc.kudla.R.id.item_list_title_prefix);
        TextView titleTextView =
                (TextView) rowView.findViewById(com.ferainc.kudla.R.id.item_list_title);
        TextView specialityTextView =
                (TextView) rowView.findViewById(com.ferainc.kudla.R.id.item_list_speciality);
        TextView addressTextView =
                (TextView) rowView.findViewById(com.ferainc.kudla.R.id.item_list_address);
        TextView distanceTextView =
                (TextView) rowView.findViewById(com.ferainc.kudla.R.id.item_list_distance);
        TextView timingsTextView =
                (TextView) rowView.findViewById(com.ferainc.kudla.R.id.item_list_timings);
        TextView contactTextView =
                (TextView) rowView.findViewById(com.ferainc.kudla.R.id.item_list_contact);


    // Get thumbnail element
        //ImageView thumbnailImageView =
          //      (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(com.ferainc.kudla.R.id.item_list_thumbnail);

        Item item = (Item) getItem(position);
        titlePrefixTextView.setText(String.valueOf(position+1) + ".");
        titleTextView.setText(item.title);
        specialityTextView.setText(item.speciality);
        addressTextView.setText(item.address);
        distanceTextView.setText(item.distance);
        timingsTextView.setText(item.timings);
        contactTextView.setText(item.contact);

        return rowView;
     }
   }
```

Item.java:

```
public class Item {

public String title;
public String speciality;
public String timings;
public String address;
public String contact;
public String distance;

public interface DataListener {
    void newDataReceived(ArrayList<Item> itemList);
}

public Item () {
    // empty default constructor, necessary for Firebase to be able to deserialize blog posts
}
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public String getSpeciality() { return speciality; }
public String getTimings() {
    return timings;
}
public String getAddress() { return address; }
public String getContact() { return contact; }
public String getDistance() { return distance; }

public static void getRecipesFromDB(final DataListener dataListener, String DBReference){
    final ArrayList<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
    final DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    final Item item = new Item();

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(DBReference);

    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            System.out.println("There are " + snapshot.getChildrenCount() + " recipes");
            Log.d("MyApp", "I am here100");

            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                Item post = postSnapshot.getValue(Item.class);

                Item item = new Item();

                item.title = post.getTitle();
                item.speciality = post.getSpeciality();
                item.timings = post.getTimings();
                item.address = post.getAddress();
                item.contact = post.getContact();
                item.distance = post.getDistance();

                itemList.add(item);
            }
            // Transaction complete, sending to listener
            dataListener.newDataReceived(itemList);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getMessage());
        }

    });

 }

}
```

ListView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context="com.ferainc.kudla.ListItemMainFragment">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/item_list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ListView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

ListView Item detail:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/list_layout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light">

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_list_title_prefix"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        tools:text="Title" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_list_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/item_list_title_prefix"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        tools:text="Title" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_list_speciality"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/item_list_title"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/center_divider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/item_list_speciality"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_list_contact_prefix"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/center_divider"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:text="Ph:"
            android:textColor="#fff092b0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_list_contact"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/center_divider"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/item_list_contact_prefix"
            android:textColor="#fff092b0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_list_address_prefix"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/item_list_contact"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:text="Address:"
            android:textColor="#fff092b0" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_list_address"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/item_list_contact"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/item_list_address_prefix"
        android:textColor="#fff092b0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_list_distance_prefix"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/item_list_address"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:text="Distance:"
            android:textColor="#fff092b0" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_list_distance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/item_list_address"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/item_list_distance_prefix"
        android:textColor="#fff092b0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_list_timings_prefix"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/item_list_distance"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:text="Timings:"
            android:textColor="#fff092b0" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_list_timings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/item_list_distance"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/item_list_timings_prefix"
        android:textColor="#fff092b0" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you add activity class also in which you are displaying the fragment

Comment: What *getRecipesFromDB* contains ?

Comment: I have added the first fragment and the class containing the getRecipesFromDB method as well. Can you have a look,

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you wanted by    `Item.getRecipesFromDB(ListItemMainFragment.this, DBReference);`
as there is no code regarding "Items" it your Fragment.
But it think it doesn't populate your ListView.
So after ListView initialisation you have to create an adapter (it is missing in your onCreateView). And then set it onto ListView.
You also may try to call newDataReceived() from onCreteView.
But I suggest you to create the Adapter in onCreteView and then in newDataReceived() you can just update data and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` instead of creating new one each time

Comment: `Item.getRecipesFromDB(ListItemMainFragment.this, DBReference)` is called from the Fragment onCreateView to retrieve the data from Firebase database. Since the data is constructed within a addValueEventListener method, i cannot return the itemList directly. Therefor itemList is passed back via dataListener. This dataListener is implemented in Fragment class where the ListView adapter is set. This code used to work all fine when I was dealing with activities but recently i moved code under Fragment and thats when I started noticing this issue.